# What is the meaning of 将切好 in 将切好的萝卜饼一块一块地放进锅里?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

接下来，拿一个平底锅，先在锅里淋一圈油，待油锅烫手时，将切好的萝卜饼一块一块地放进锅里。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 19. What is the meaning of 将切好?

Probably 将 means soon or also, and 切好 means cut done, or cut completed? Simply said, 切好 is an adjective means cut or having cut? Chopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

将(take)切好的(the already cut/sliced)萝卜饼(radish cake/pie).

Note at here, 将 equates to 拿/取/把.

Answer (score 0):

将=把

**将**切好的萝卜饼一块一块地放进锅里。

**把**萝卜饼放进平底锅里

切好的萝卜饼  (the) chopped-up radish pancake

You have radish fetish??